# Search for rows containing coordinates in Database [SQL]

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, regex

I have a very big database of around 20000 entries. Some of the entries contain coordinates with six or seven numvers, but not in the field "coordinates", but in the field "remarks".

I'd like to find all entries that have coordniates within their remarks-field.

Until now, I made a connection to my database, defined a cursor and tried a query of the following appearence:

```
query = " SELECT INDEX 
          FROM GeoTest.dbo.Tabelle_Bohrung 
          WHERE BO_BEMERKUNG NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' "
```

INDEX is the ID (distinct) for every entry.

Well, I think i should use a regular expression to catch the coordinates.

I really don't know how to phrase my query for catching what I want.

I would be really thankful for every suggestion and help!!

So here is an original example of the remarks-field:

```
        ID      remarks
LINE1   ID 1    - 2 Bohrungen vorhanden - Koordinate 2. Bohrung: 524'656 / 158'307
LINE2   ID 2    Schichtbeschrieb siehe BL 16.Z.03
LINE3   ID 3    - Koordinate 2. Bohrung 510'055 / 165'687
LINE4   ID 4    - Bohrprofil siehe Kataster - Nummer 2944
LINE5   ID 5    - Tiefe der Bohrung 60 m
```

In my case, i would like to get the ID of LINE1 and LINE3 with my query.

Comment: Do you mean you have records like `2900915.47` or `2900915.47, 1369025.59` or `2900915.47, 1369025.59, 8566627.53`? Try replacing `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` with `REGEXP '^(,? *[0-9]+[.][0-9]+)+$'`, or `REGEXP '^[0-9]+[.][0-9]+(, [0-9]+[.][0-9]+)*$'`

Comment: First the  python code is irrelevant, you could make your question simpler if you focus only on the sql part. Second, How can we help you if you dont even know what pattern are the coordinates on that field. Try to include several samples so we can understand better. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: The coordinates I am searching for, are for example: 2900915.47  or   1369025.59   or     2850080     or     136002    or    1350750   and so on...

Comment: Can you post an example of the data you retrieve from the query?

Comment: Then try `REGEXP '^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?(, [0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?)*$'` if there can be multiple comma separated coords. Just `REGEXP '^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$` should do if there is just one in an entry.

Comment: I have updated my answer to match updated question

Comment: Is your *original example of the remarks field* just *one* entry? Other words: Is the remarks column filled with (badly) structured data? Or is each line you poste related to ever one record in your table? From the caption one could think, that only the "- 2 Bohrungen ..." is the remarks... Please clearify!

Comment: each row i wrote is one individual entry of my database.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually using a regex if you use `LIKE`. It only supports literals (obviously), char classes (alternative characters/ranges within a `[]`), wildcards (with `_`) and anchoring (by default it's anchored: `%` is used to un-anchor, and can also be used like `.*` in the middle).

If you want to ensure there are 2 numbers in a coordinate (each with a fractional part indicated with `'`), separated by a space padded `/`, you could do: `LIKE '%[0-9]\'[0-9]% / %[0-9]\'[0-9]%'`